# Jssor slideshow transitions

Tags: jquery, slideshow, jssor

I have a Jssor slideshow using Jquery on my page that works with arrow keys, click and drag, and automatic sliding intervals, but I can not get transitions to work. When I try and include `slideshow-transition-builder-controller.min.js` it mostly breaks the slideshow. This is the code I have currently. I just want the basic fade transition.

`<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var _SlideshowTransitions = [
            {
                $Duration:700,
                $Opacity:2,
                $Brother:{
                    $Duration:1000,
                    $Opacity:2
                }
            }
        ];
        var options = { 
            $AutoPlay: true,
            $AutoPlaySteps: 1,
            $AutoPlayInterval: 6000,
            $PauseOnHover: 1, 
            $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,
            $SlideDuration: 300,
            $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20,
            $PlayOrientation: 1,
            $DragOrientation: 1
        };
        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('slider1_container', options);
    });
</script>`

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please add $SlideshowOptions

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var _SlideshowTransitions = [
            {
                $Duration:700,
                $Opacity:2,
                $Brother:{
                    $Duration:1000,
                    $Opacity:2
                }
            }
        ];
        var options = { 
            $AutoPlay: true,
            $AutoPlaySteps: 1,
            $AutoPlayInterval: 6000,
            $PauseOnHover: 1, 
            $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,
            $SlideDuration: 300,
            $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20,
            $PlayOrientation: 1,
            $DragOrientation: 1,
            $SlideshowOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable slideshow or not
                $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,                 //[Required] Class to create instance of slideshow
                $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,            //[Required] An array of slideshow transitions to play slideshow
                $TransitionsOrder: 1,                           //[Optional] The way to choose transition to play slide, 1 Sequence, 0 Random
                $ShowLink: true                                    //[Optional] Whether to bring slide link on top of the slider when slideshow is running, default value is false
            }
        };
        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('slider1_container', options);
    });
</script>
```

Reference: http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-slideshow-jquery.html